# What is the difference between @EnvironmentObject and @ObservedObject?

Tags: swiftui, observedobject, property-wrapper, environmentobject

I have been reading about the property wrappers in SwiftUI and I see that they do a great job, but one thing which I really don't get is the difference between **@EnvironmentObject** and **@ObservedObject**.

From what I learned so far, I see that **@EnvironmentObject** is used when we have an object that is needed in various places in our app but we don't need to pass it through all of them. For example if we have hierarchy A -> B -> C -> D and the object is created at A, it is saved in the environment so that we can pass it directly from A to D, if D needs it.

If we use **@ObservedObject** which is created at A and needs to be passed to D, then we need to go through B and C as well.

But I still don't know how to decide which one to use.
Here are 2 example projects which I made:

```
struct ContentView2: View {
 
   var order = Order2()

   var body: some View {
      VStack {
           EditView2()
           DisplayView2()
       }
       .environmentObject(order)
   }
}
struct EditView2: View {
   @EnvironmentObject var user: Order2
 
   var body: some View {
       HStack{
       TextField("Fruit", text: $user.item)
       }
   }
}
struct DisplayView2: View {
   @EnvironmentObject var user: Order2
   var body: some View {
       VStack{
       Text(user.item)
       }
   }
}
class Order2: ObservableObject {
       @Published var item = "Orange"
   }
```

and

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var order = Order()
    
    var body: some View {
       VStack {
            EditView(order: order)
            DisplayView(order: order)
        }
    }
}
struct EditView: View {
    @ObservedObject var order: Order
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
        TextField("Fruit", text: $order.item)
        }
    }
}
struct DisplayView: View {
      @ObservedObject var order: Order
      var body: some View {
        VStack{
        Text(order.item)
        }
    }
}
class Order: ObservableObject {
    @Published var item = "Apple"
}
```

Both codes do the same update of the view. Also both ContentViews, pass an **Order** object. The difference is that Environment passes  **.environmentObject(order)** and Observed passes it directly **EditView(order: order)**. For me, both do same job, only their declaration is different, therefore I would appreciate some explanation or a better example.

Comment: The difference is only in injection... ObservedObject you must inject like any other property - at each init, but environment object is injected only *once* at root of view hierarchy... and available for any far deep view. That's it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As you've noticed an `@ObservedObject` needs to be passed from view to view. It may be better for a simple view hierarchy when you don't have too many views.

---

Let's assume you have the following hierarchy:

```
ViewA -> ViewB -> ViewC -> ViewD
```

Now if you want your `@ObservedObject` from the `ViewA` to be in the `ViewB` there's no problem with passing it directly in `init`.

But what if you want it in the `ViewD` as well? And what if you don't need it in the `ViewB` and `ViewC`?

With an `@ObservedObject` you'd need to manually pass it from the `ViewA` to the `ViewB` and then to the `ViewC`, and then to the `ViewD`. And you'd need to declare it in every child view.

With an `@EnvironmentObject` it's easy - just pass it to the top-level view:

```
ViewA().environmentObject(someObservableObject)
```

Then you only declare it in the view that uses it - this may make your code more readable.

---

**Note**

*Every* object in the environment (view hierarchy) can access the injected `@EnvironmentObject`. If you don't want this (privacy is important) you may need to pass it as an `@ObservedObject` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed description. To summarize it, when I declare @EnvironmentObject at ViewA all child views will have access to it. Does it work also for sheet views? For example, I have a .sheet presented from ViewA

Comment: @Dakata No, unfortunately you need to inject it again to your sheet. But only once when you call it. Then all child views in the sheet will have access to your EnvironmentObject. Think of it like a sheet has its own environment.

Comment: Note that you can use private types as EnvironmentObject which stops scopes that don't know about that type from accessing it

Comment: This is the best explanation, I understood it fully. Thank you!

Comment: Further to previous comments, EnvironmentObject works with sheets too.